# Gitlab CI Cache with VirtualBox Runner

Tags: caching, gitlab, virtualbox, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Gitlab CI VirtualBox runners do not support the Gitlab CI cache (as layed out in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/virtualbox.html)). However, I require a cache (primarily to cache my maven and node folders).

Are there known home-made workarounds/scripts, best practices or third party libraries for caching in VirtualBox runners?

*Or in short*: How can I cache specific folders when using Gitlab CI VirtualBox runners?

Comment: Check if you can mount a local directory in the VirtualBox (my gut says you should be able to), if not set up an FTP server on the host and copy the files you need cached onto/from it.

Comment: The other solution would be to look into a caching proxy for the repositories.